# Logstash 2.3.4 How to load nested document in elasticsearch using logstash-jdbc plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc, logstash-filter

I am currently using elasticsearch 2.3.4 and logstash 2.3.4 to load relational data from Oracle db into my elasticsearch index using logstash-jdbc plugin. As suggested in various posts, I am using aggregate filter for this. Still I am not able to load the inner nested object in the document. The values are not getting mapped to fields and are displayed as NULL.

I have two related entities with following data:

```
    CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
        id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
        id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL,
        departmentid NUMBER,
        CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (departmentid) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(id)
    ) 


    insert into DEPARTMENT values (1, 'dept1');
    insert into DEPARTMENT values (2, 'dept2');
    insert into DEPARTMENT values (3, 'dept3');
    insert into DEPARTMENT values (4, 'dept4');

    insert into EMPLOYEE values (1, 'emp1', 1);
    insert into EMPLOYEE values (2, 'emp2', 1);
    insert into EMPLOYEE values (3, 'emp3', 1);
    insert into EMPLOYEE values (4, 'emp4', 2);
    insert into EMPLOYEE values (5, 'emp5', 2);
    insert into EMPLOYEE values (6, 'emp6', 3);`
```

Here is my mapping:

```
   {
        "mappings": {
            "departments": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "deptName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },          
                    "employee_details": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "empId": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "empName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my logstash configuration:

```
  input{
        jdbc{
            jdbc_validate_connection => true
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db"
            jdbc_user => "user"
            jdbc_password => "pwd"
            jdbc_driver_library => "../vendor/jar/ojdbc14.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            statement => "SELECT 
                            department.id AS id,
                            department.name AS deptName,
                            employee.id AS empId,
                            employee.name AS empName
                        FROM  department LEFT JOIN employee  
                        ON department.id = employee.departmentid
                        ORDER BY id"
        }
    }

    filter{
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{id}"
            code => "
            map['id'] = event['id']
            map['deptName'] = event['deptName'] #solution - deptName should be in smaller case and other fields too.
            map['employee_details'] ||= []
            map['employee_details'] << {'empId' => event['empId], 'empName' => event['empName'] }
            "

            push_previous_map_as_event => true
            timeout => 5
            timeout_tags => ['aggregated']
        }       
    }

    output{
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
        elasticsearch{
            action => "index"
            index => "my_index"
            document_type => "departments"
            document_id => "%{id}"
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
        }
    }
```

When i perform a XGET on all documents: 
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search/?pretty=true&q=*:*

The values are not mapped to fields and displayed as NULL:

```
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "departments",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "id": 2,
              "deptName": null,
              "employee_details": [
                {
                  "empId": null,
                  "empName": null
                },
                {
                  "empId": null,
                  "empName": null
                }
              ],
              "@version": "1",
              "@timestamp": "2019-05-14T10:47:33.477Z",
              "tags": [
                "aggregated"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "departments",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "id": 4,
              "deptname": "dept4",
              "empid": null,
              "empname": null,
              "@version": "1",
              "@timestamp": "2019-05-14T10:47:33.367Z",
              "deptName": null,
              "employee_details": [
                {
                  "empId": null,
                  "empName": null
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "departments",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "id": 1,
              "deptName": null,
              "employee_details": [
                {
                  "empId": null,
                  "empName": null
                },
                {
                  "empId": null,
                  "empName": null
                },
                {
                  "empId": null,
                  "empName": null
                }
              ],
              "@version": "1",
              "@timestamp": "2019-05-14T10:47:33.477Z",
              "tags": [
                "aggregated"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "departments",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "id": 3,
              "deptName": null,
              "employee_details": [
                {
                  "empId": null,
                  "empName": null
                }
              ],
              "@version": "1",
              "@timestamp": "2019-05-14T10:47:33.492Z",
              "tags": [
                "aggregated"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

rubydebug suggests the values are set to 'nil'. Could anyone please help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Here is a snippet from stdout for document with id = 1:

```
{
            "id" => 1.0,
      "deptname" => "dept1",
         "empid" => 1.0,
       "empname" => "emp1",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2019-05-14T12:32:14.272Z"
}
{
            "id" => 1.0,
      "deptname" => "dept1",
         "empid" => 2.0,
       "empname" => "emp2",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2019-05-14T12:32:15.272Z"
}
{
            "id" => 1.0,
      "deptname" => "dept1",
         "empid" => 3.0,
       "empname" => "emp3",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2019-05-14T12:32:15.272Z"
}
{
                  "id" => 1.0,
            "deptName" => nil,
    "employee_details" => [
        [0] {
              "empId" => nil,
            "empName" => nil
        },
        [1] {
              "empId" => nil,
            "empName" => nil
        },
        [2] {
              "empId" => nil,
            "empName" => nil
        }
    ],
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2019-05-14T12:32:15.381Z",
                "tags" => [
        [0] "aggregated"
    ]
}
```

Comment: If anyone stumbles at this post looking for a solution then this configuration totally works as it should except every field should be in small cases. Like map['deptname'] = event['deptname']. I got help from this post: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-2-3-x-how-to-load-nested-objects-in-elasticsearch-index-using-logstash-jdbc-plugin/180988

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me .

```
input {
    jdbc{
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "----/employees"
        jdbc_user => "---"
        jdbc_password => "--"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/ilsa/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT  
            e.emp_no as employee_number, 
            birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date, t.title  AS titlename, 
            t.from_date AS titlefrom_date, t.to_date AS titleto_date, d.dept_no AS departmentnumber, 
            ds.dept_name AS departmentname, d.from_date AS departmentfrom_date, d.to_date AS departmentto_date 
        FROM employees e 
        LEFT JOIN(titles t, dept_emp d, departments ds) 
        ON(e.emp_no = t.emp_no AND e.emp_no = d.emp_no AND d.dept_no = ds.dept_no AND t.from_date < d.to_date AND t.to_date >   d.from_date) 
ORDER BY e.emp_no ASC"
    }

}
filter {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{employee_number}"
        code => "
            map['employee_number'] = event.get('employee_number')
            map['birth_date'] = event.get('birth_date')
            map['first_name'] = event.get('first_name')
            map['last_name'] = event.get('last_name')
            map['gender'] = event.get('gender')
            map['hire_date'] = event.get('hire_date')
            map['roles'] ||= []
            map['roles'] << {

                'title.name' => event.get('titlename'),
                'title.from_date' => event.get('titlefrom_date'),
                'title.to_date' => event.get('titleto_date'),
                'department.number' => event.get('departmentnumber'),
                'department.name' => event.get('departmentname'),
                'department.from_date' => event.get('departmentfrom_date'),
                'department.to_date' => event.get('departmentto_date')
            }
        event.cancel()"
        push_previous_map_as_event => true
        timeout => 30
    }
}
output {
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch{
        action => "index"
        index => "employees"
        document_type => "employee"
        document_id => "%{employee_number}"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to make use of jdbc streaming in logstash filter plugin.
Check this post
[Inserting Nested Objects using Logstash](https://xyzcoder.github.io/2020/07/29/indexing-documents-using-logstash-and-python.html)

For example, I am taking Stackoverflow Posts and Users as an example. Here Post is parent table and it is associated with Users table on OwnerUserId. So my plugin configuration is

```
    input {
    jdbc {
           jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/javalib/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar"
           jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
           jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://host.docker.internal;database=StackOverflow2010;user=pavan;password=pavankumar@123"
           jdbc_user => "pavan"
           jdbc_password => "pavankumar@123"
           statement => "select top 500 * from StackOverflow2010.dbo.Posts p "
        }
}

filter{
    jdbc_streaming {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/javalib/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://host.docker.internal;database=StackOverflow2010;user=pavan;password=pavankumar@123"
    jdbc_user => "pavan"
    jdbc_password => "pavankumar@123"
    statement => "select * from StackOverflow2010.dbo.Users u where u.Id = :owneruserid"
    parameters => {"owneruserid" => "owneruserid"}
    target => "user_details"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200", "http://elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "stackoverflow_top_user"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```